# Regarding SSL Setup on Apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

I want to setup my SSL certificate on my subdomain

account.mydomain.com, so I copied the 000-default-ssl.conf which came with the apache2 LAMP setup.

I uploaded my .bundle and .crt file into /var/www

I did

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

and it confirmed that mod rewrite is turned on from apache2 return message.

My ssl still does not work, when I visit

```
account.mydomain.com
```

it says my permission is not verified, this was previously used at namecheap hosting, I got the bundle and crt file, and at namecheap, the setup was easier because there's a option at cpanel whereby I just let the namecheap guy setup for me.

Now I change to an `unmanage` hosting so it's a bit harder for me to attempt to setup ssl for the first time.

Below is my SSL file, I did a2ensite my-ssl.conf and did an apache2 reload

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName account.bizdomain.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/biz/account
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/account_wizassets_com.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/account_wizassets_com.ca-bundle
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>    

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

<Directory /var/www/biz/account>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If I list my files

```
root@K8:/var/www# ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5624 May  4 14:17 account_bizdomain_com.ca-bundle
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1931 May  4 14:17 account_bizdomain_com.crt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 24 12:09 html
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May  4 22:19 biz
```

Comment: "permission is not verified" What is the exact message? If you are on a browser, you can look for additional technical details that show the exact error.

Comment: @Ajoy This website does not supply ownership information, verified by lamp, my ssl is by Comodo, positive SSL

Comment: From this [answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/14062/18390), it seems that the organization is missing in the cert

Comment: I think you have referenced the wrong certificates. `SSLCertificateFile` should be `/var/www/account_bizdomain_com.crt`.

Comment: `SSLCertificateKeyFile` should have the key that was used to sign your certificate

Comment: If the above setup does not work (there might be issues in mobile browsers), you will have to complete the certificate chain. [Create the chain cert file](http://blog.ajoyoommen.com/24/chaining-ssl-certificates) and add to `SSLCertificateChainFile`

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced the wrong certificate. It should be

```
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/account_bizdomain_com.crt
```